# identity test game of life

Tags: python, pytest, identity

I'm writing the conway's game code in python. My code is like this:

```py
def update_board(board: list[list[int]]) -> list[list[int]]:
    rows = len(board)
    cols = len(board[0])
    count = 0
    copy_board = deepcopy(board)
    indx = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
    indy = [-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1]
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            for k, value in enumerate(indx):
                if check(i + value, j + indy[k], rows,
                         cols) and copy_board[i + indx[k]][j + indy[k]]:
                    count += 1
            # Apply the rule to each cell
            if count < 2 or count > 3:
                board[i][j] = 0
            elif count == 3:
                board[i][j] = 1
            # Reset the count for the next cell
            count = 0
    return board
```

It need to pass through the identity test:

```
def test_is_not_identity() -> None:
   """Test board update is not done in place."""
   board = [[0 for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(4)]
   assert board is not update_board(board)
```

and the stills test (I don't know what it does):

```py
def test_stills(name: str, proto: str) -> None:
    """Test still lifes."""
    board = parse_board(proto)
    assert board == update_board(deepcopy(board)), name
```

but it doesn't pass although I updated the board in place so I don't understand.

Comment: I believe what is desired is that you update (and return) the copy, not the original board.

Comment: The test says: _"Test board update is *not* done in place."_  but then you say _"it doesn't pass although I updated the board in place"_ ...so you've done the opposite of what the test is expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the `copy_board` instead of `board`. Also moodify `copy_booard` instead of `board` itself

```
def update_board(board: list[list[int]]) -> list[list[int]]:
    rows = len(board)
    cols = len(board[0])
    count = 0
    copy_board = deepcopy(board)
    indx = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
    indy = [-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1]
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            for k, value in enumerate(indx):
                if check(i + value, j + indy[k], rows,
                         cols) and board[i + indx[k]][j + indy[k]]:
                    count += 1
            # Apply the rule to each cell
            if count < 2 or count > 3:
                copy_board[i][j] = 0
            elif count == 3:
                copy_board[i][j] = 1
            # Reset the count for the next cell
            count = 0
    return copy_board
```

Comment: using list whoud probably lead to long computation time though